# Print from Windows Mobile Application

Tags: windows, printing, mobile, zebra-printers

I am developing a windows mobile application using dot net framework 3.5.

I want to print a reciept from my application on a bluetooth printer Zebra MZ 320. That reciept will contain some text and some images. Can someone guide me how i can achieve it :)

Thanks and Regards,
Mrinal Jaiswal

Answer (score 2):

Use the ZebraSDK for Windows Mobile (or the appropriate platform you are targeting) to send ZPL II code to the printer you are targeting.  You will need either a Bluetooth or Ethernet [enabled Zebra Printer](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/software/SDK.html).

Personally, I have avoided all SDKs and simply used GDI+ to create a bitmap, encoded the bitmap according to the Zebra spec and then sent the bitmap with some wrapper ZPL II code to the printer via .NET TCP connection.

Reading the ZPL Programming Guides both volume I and II will definitely help you on your way to learning how to do what you want.  There really are no easy shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 32feet library on codeplex